# How can I return a result and a written statement from a function?

Tags: r, function

I want this function to return both the result (number) and the text.

```
sum_of_squares_cubes <- function(x,y) {
  sq = x^2 + y^2
  cube = x^3 + y^3
  return(list(sq, cube))
  cat("The sum of squares is", sq, "\n" ,
      "The sum of cubes is", cube, "\n" ,
      )
}
```

Doing the above only returns the number of the result.

Desired output:

```
sum_of_squares_cubes(2,3)
13
35
"The sum of squares is 13"
"The sum of cubes is 35"
```

Comment: put the `return` statement after `cat`

Comment: no code is executed after the `return()`. Put the `cat()` just before if you want to print.

Comment: But, but, but.  `cat` doesn't "return" anything. It works entirely by side-effect.

Comment: My guess is OP wants text output to the console, rather than `return`ed. Can you clarify? Do you want to be able to assign these strings to an object, or do you just want to see it in the console?

Comment: @Gregor: Either way is fine. :)

Comment: @lizzie, if you want it printed to the console (which is what I had assumed given that you used `cat`) just switch the lines that @Gregor and I mentioned. If you want the text to be part of the returned object, you can do what's suggested in the answers. By the way, you have an extra comma at the end of you `cat` call.

Comment: It works fine @Gabe. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that these other folks have the same confusion as do you and that you will be happy with their advice, but to actually *return* multiple items of dissimilar class (which is what you asked) you do need a *single* list (of possibly complex structure).

```
sum_of_squares_cubes <- function(x,y) {
  sq = x^2 + y^2
  cube = x^3 + y^3
  return(list(sq, cube,  sqmsg=paste("The sum of squares is", sq, "\n") , 
                         cubemsg= paste("The sum of cubes is", cube, "\n") 
       )) 
   }

> sum_of_squares_cubes(2,4)
[[1]]
[1] 20

[[2]]
[1] 72

$sqmsg
[1] "The sum of squares is 20 \n"

$cubemsg
[1] "The sum of cubes is 72 \n"
```

Comment: There is something missing here. I'm getting an error.

Comment: This is the correct method, just adding that you should never use `cat()` for returning results as you will need to rerun the function to obtain results again.

Comment: Lot's of `print` methods (and `summary` methods) use `cat` and users then need to use `capture.output`

Answer (score 2):

Modify the function to do this instead?

```
sum_of_squares_cubes <- function(x,y) {
  sq = x^2 + y^2
  cube = x^3 + y^3
  text <- paste("The sum of squares is ", sq, "\n",
                "The sum of cubes is ", cube, "\n", sep = '')
  return(list(sq, cube, text))
}
```

Comment: The output is almost great. Just the last part is weird.
 
`"The sum of squares is 13\nThe sum of cubes is 35\n"`

Comment: Unless you put it to some output device, that is the character vector representation of that. You take it and `cat`, you will see the function do the correct thing.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simpler solution with sprintf:

```
sum_of_squares_cubes <- function(x,y) {
  sq = x^2 + y^2
  cube = x^3 + y^3
  text1 <- sprintf("The sum of squares is %d", sq)
  text2 <- sprintf("and the sum of cubes is %d",  cube)
  return(cat(c("\n", sq, "\n", cube, "\n", text1, "\n", text2)))
}
```

and the result looks like:

```
 13 
 35 
 The sum of squares is 13 
 and the sum of cubes is 35
```